# Pagination and Filtering on EmberJS

Tags: rest, ember.js, pagination, ember-data

EmberJS encourages us to rely on path everywhere where possible and it's easy to use parameters on enter route to setup controller properly. But what if you don't care about transferring location to someone and want to use complex filtering combined with pagination dynamically? I'm going to show what I figured out. This may be useful as long as I haven't met too much relevant guides on my path.

Answer (score 2):

First off, what I have on server side:

1) I use has_scope, so query params are transferring right in the url.
2) My template produced by index action looks like this:
{"actors": [..models go here..], "meta": {"total": 10, "page": 1}}
So I pass total amount of pages and current page with json response.

Here is the route:

```
Caster.ActorsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend

  model: ->
    @store.findQuery 'actor',
      search: @get('controller.term')
      page: @get('controller.page')

  actions:
    refresh: ->
      @model().then (data) =>
        @set 'controller.model', data
```

Here we repeat what setupController does on 'refresh' event. This event will be sent by controller:

```
Caster.ActorsIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend

  term: ''
  page: 1

  terms: ( -> @reload() ).observes('term', 'page')
  meta: ( -> @store.metadataFor('actor') ).property('model')
  updatePage: ( -> @set 'page', @get('meta.page') ).observes('model')

  reload: -> @get('target').send('refresh')
```

All that left is to build pagination widget that will change 'page' property of the controller and cause reload of the collection. This happens as well when 'term' property gets changed.

The one issue here is that there are no controller properties available on route initialization, so first time you'll get non scoped collection.